# Getting 404 for crud generated using Gii

Tags: http-status-code-404, crud, gii

Error page-[404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8DYZ.png)

crud form details-
[crud form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0mFi.png)

I cannot access the URL, I already made a crud operation based on documentation but when I create my own structure its showing page not found.
If you want I can also post model generation page.
Thanking in advance

folder structure->

```
 - models
-- UserModel
-controllers
--LoginFormController
-views
--loginform
---index.php
```

controller code

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\UserModel;
use app\models\UserSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;

/**
 * LoginFormController implements the CRUD actions for UserModel model.
 */
class LoginFormController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'delete' => ['POST'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all UserModel models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new UserSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single UserModel model.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new UserModel model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new UserModel();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->username]);
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Updates an existing UserModel model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->username]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing UserModel model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param string $id
     * @return mixed
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * Finds the UserModel model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param string $id
     * @return UserModel the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = UserModel::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        }

        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

UserModel

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "user".
 *
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $password
 */
class UserModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            [['username', 'password'], 'string', 'max' => 52],
            [['username'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'Username',
            'password' => 'Password',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out just had to use '-' in the url as uppercases LoginForm is interpreted as login-form in url